# Protection before reading paged memory from kernel

Tags: windows, memory, driver, windows-kernel

I have kernel driver and I want to read the memory of a usermode app.

How can I check the paged memory if swapping will be success or not (when pages are written to the disk and we have problems with disk or whatever)?

Comment: In Linux, you always copy the user data into kernel first, with `copy_from_user`, Isn't there an equivalent in Windows?

Comment: You know that user memory you want to read is paged out and know in advance if  loading it to memory will be successfull? Or just want to read it guaranteeing that your driver does not crash?

Comment: No, I didn't find an equivalent func for Windows...

Comment: Yes, I want to read it and not to crash my driver

Comment: I also use ProbeForRead, but I'm not sure it helps with paged memory that can't be found on disk and be restored it to physical memory

Comment: you need simply read inside *__try/__except* block and handle possible error. paged memory or not - does not matter at all here. or memory range valid or not (will be exception, handled by  *__try/__except*. and of course *IRQL* must be lower than dispatch (usual passive level)

Answer (score 0):

@RbMm's answer is correct. If you are not at dispatch level, you wrap the probing of the memory in a __try/__except block with the filter set to catch the exception. You need to figure out from the exception or Mm whether the page is indeed not-present due to being completely invalid (i.e., never allocated) or paged-out/demand-zero-inited/copy-on-write/etc.